# What really happens if I run Tukey without running ANOVA first?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, multiple-comparisons, tukey-hsd-test

I see that the theory says that if I want to test for difference in mean between 3+ groups I should use ANOVA first, and if ANOVA rejects the null hypothesis then I might want to look into Tukey as a post-hoc test to find which groups' means really differ.

My question then is: why not running Tukey directly? What really happens if I run Tukey without running ANOVA first? Which are the risks/implications of that?

The intuition tells me that if Tukey finds some significant differences, then ANOVA should have found it, too. When is that not the case?

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question, but it is certainly possible to find significant pairwise differences after a non-significant ANOVA.  See e.g. [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28845/what-if-an-overall-anova-is-not-significant-but-specific-contrasts-are)

Comment: Running the F test before Turkey is actually a bad idea. See a book about multiple testing/comparisons.