# How to interpret the interaction coefficient

Tags: interaction, interpretation, stata

This is a fixed effect panel model in Stata. Income group has 4 categories: Low income, Lower middle income, Upper middle income and High income. Here below, I put the interaction coefficient values for the model. I would like to know the effect of financial service (findex) on Carbon emissions. Other control variables are: per capita gdp, consumption expenditure, renewable energy and trade amount.

How will I interpret the coefficient value from the interaction?

```
Co2pc                |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
Low income           |  -.0165589   .0194985    -0.85   0.396    -.0548202    .0217024
Lower middle income  |    .010723   .0103074     1.04   0.298    -.0095029    .0309488
Upper middle income  |    .042023   .0081153     5.18   0.000     .0260985    .0579475
```

I tried this code:

```
xtreg Co2pc findex GDPpc Cons_exp Energy Trade i.incomegroup##c. findex,fe
```

Comment: See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/597267/28500) for interpreting an interaction between a continuous predictor and a 4-level categorical predictor. The coefficient for `findex` itself is the slope when `incomegroup` is at its reference level, "High income" here. The interaction coefficients are _differences_ from that slope for each of the other levels of `incomegroup`.