# FDR adjusted p-values and q-values

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I am currently working on adjusting p-values in `R` using the False Discovery Rate (FDR) method and have encountered some confusion regarding the basic concepts of adjusted p-values and q-values. Adjusted p-values result from applying a correction method to control for multiple testing.
Indeed in https://genome.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/help/qValue.html, it's stated that: 'The q-value is an analog of the p-value that incorporates multiple testing correction. The q-value is defined as the minimum false discovery rate at which an observed score is deemed significant.'
Otherwise, read through a relevant answer https://support.bioconductor.org/p/49864/ , which emphasizes that adjusted p-values and q-values are similar but not quite the same.

I understand the algorithm for calculating q-values, and I understand that repeated values might be encountered. However, I am still seeking clarification on the differences between adjusted p-values and q-values, if any.

To illustrate my point, I'm using a simple example in R. Imagine that I have the p-values of a two sample t-test with alpha=0.05 conducted on the same individuals for 43 variables:

```
set.seed(6655)
p_values <- abs(rnorm(43,mean = 0, sd=0.25))
adjusted_p_values <- p.adjust(p_values, method = "fdr")
```

Showing the results, I get:

[image]

Looking at the table, I would say that after the FDR correction I cannot reject the null hypothesis of no differences between the two groups, for each of the variables. Is it this correct? Otherwise, would it be also true that  minimum false discovery rate at which that test may be called significant is 0.069 i.e. for variable 43?

**EDIT:**
at this link http://viiia.org/fdrFigs/?scale=1920 it is stated that 'a q-value measures the False Discovery Rate (FDR) you would incur by accepting the given test and every test with a smaller p-value (and maybe even larger p-values, if they improve the FDR).', so that for my data i would say that for the variable 43 the test has a 6.9% chance of being a false positive. But what about for the variables 9 and 21 for example? Is it correct to say that both the tests have a 32.68% chance of being a false positive?
I am wondering if this is the only way of interpreting qvalues or there are more straightforward meanings.

Comment: I can't reproduce your numbers. Can you check them.

Comment: you're right but i forgot the correct seed. I will edit the question to be as close as possible to the original

Comment: This still isn't quite right.  What you have in your `q-value` column is the adjusted p-value.  What's in your `adjusted` column is the adjusted p-value before the correction that forces them to be monotonic with p.

Comment: the `adjusted` column is something that i calculated by hand. it was just to understand why then i will get repeated q-values

Comment: I can't help much with your question, but I do think that it is worth considering the utility of FDR and other 'corrections' in gene association  studies. Given that surveys of a large number of genes and their associations can properly be thought of as preliminary studies, how do 'corrections' that increase the false negatives help? Any positives should be tested in a designed experiment or, at least, with fresh data and that gives excellent protection against false positives. You can rank the interestingness of the associations on the basis of the raw p-values. How does FDR help?

Comment: @MichaelLew Thank you for your comment.  I haven't clarified that this is not a gene association study, but rather a case-control examination of physiological responses across groups. With multiple tests on the same subjects, there's a concern that significant results might be due to chance. Applying Bonferroni correction yields a stringent p-value of 0.00116 for 43 tests, making significance unlikely. Opting for FDR correction provides a more balanced approach, reducing the risk of false positives while preserving sensitivity to detect genuine associations.

Comment: OK, so not genes, but my main point still applies: your p-values give you a rank order of the strengths of evidence in the data against each null. Why would you not choose which comparisons are most important using that ranking along with what you know about the physiology? FDR is not as 'wasteful' as some other approaches, but it is still not really relevant to most stages of the scientific process. See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630316/how-many-p-value-observations-do-you-think-are-required-before-doing-fdr-correct/630324#630324

Comment: One more comment on the multiplicity 'corrections' in this case. Many physiological measurements correlate with each other to a greater or lesser degree. The correlation will frequently be non-linear and may be expressed over a limited range, but measurements that a medical expert might choose to try when researching a disease would often be strongly correlated. That lack of independence is not part of the usual calculations for 'corrections' for multiplicity. Statistics (and most statisticians) almost always know less about the system under study than the researcher...

Answer (score 3):

I think you are getting confused because you are conflating two separate FDR procedures: 1) the BH FDR method implemented by `p.adjust`, and 2) the Storey pFDR 'q-value' procedure. In practice, however, the term 'q-value' has come to mean 'FDR-adjusted p-value', rather than specifically the Storey pFDR qvalue. The two methods will, however, yield identical results when the null is true. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-value_(statistics)) is a good resource in this case.

I can't reproduce your q-values, since you do not provide code, but note that the distribution you provide is not a valid p-value distribution, as there is no value greater than 0.5, which is an extremely odd outcome after having conducted 43 tests. As a result, I think the q-values you've calculated are not correct (the `qvalue` package throws an error because it isn't a valid distribution).

Here's a valid example:

```
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("qvalue")
library(qvalue)

set.seed(6655)
p.dat  =data.frame(p_values = sapply(c(1:100),function(X){cor.test(rnorm(n = 1000,mean = 0,sd = 1),rnorm(n = 1000,mean = 0,sd = 1))$p.value}))
p.dat$p_fdr_BH = p.adjust(p.dat$p_values, method = "fdr")
p.dat$p_fdr_q = qvalue(p = p.dat$p_values,fdr.level = .05)$qvalues
p.dat = p.dat[order(p.dat$p_values),]

head(p.dat)

     p_values  p_fdr_BH   p_fdr_q
13 0.00677724 0.5436862 0.5436862
42 0.01423080 0.5436862 0.5436862
31 0.02289128 0.5436862 0.5436862
26 0.02373593 0.5436862 0.5436862
90 0.03139673 0.5436862 0.5436862
51 0.03262117 0.5436862 0.5436862
```

And here's another example where the null is false. We can see that two procedures yield different adjusted p-values.

```
install.packages('clusterGeneration')
install.packages('mvtnorm')

set.seed(12345)
cov.mat = clusterGeneration::genPositiveDefMat(dim = 101,covMethod = "eigen")
dat = mvtnorm::rmvnorm(n = 1000,mean = rep(0,101),sigma = cov.mat$Sigma)

y = dat[,1]
x = dat[,-1]

p.dat2  =data.frame(p_values =apply(x, 2,function(X){cor.test(y,X)$p.value},simplify = TRUE))
p.dat2$p_fdr_BH = p.adjust(p.dat2$p_values, method = "fdr")
p.dat2$p_fdr_q = qvalue(p = p.dat2$p_values,fdr.level = .05)$qvalues
p.dat2 = p.dat2[order(p.dat2$p_values),]

head(p.dat2)

       p_values     p_fdr_BH      p_fdr_q
83 2.283144e-30 2.283144e-28 1.214469e-28
31 4.430523e-16 2.215261e-14 1.178360e-14
89 2.632440e-08 8.774801e-07 4.667566e-07
13 9.638186e-08 2.409547e-06 1.281706e-06
47 1.840107e-07 3.680213e-06 1.957610e-06
11 5.333084e-07 8.888474e-06 4.728031e-06
```