What is the best statistical analysis to analyse significant differences in different metabolites over time (time 0,24 and 48 hours)
I have 40 different metabolites where I measured their concentration at time 0, 24 and 48 hours. I would like to know if there are significant differences over time in each metabolite. I am not interested if there are or not differences between metabolites. I was thinking in running one way Anova repeated measures + Tukey tests per metabolite. so at the end I would have 40 different analysis (Anova + Tukey).

Can you clarify how many data points you have for a single metabolite at a single time point? Just 1, or 10, or ? Then maybe I can help you.

Are the timepoints assessed because the metabolites grow over time?

I have 3 data points per each time per metabolite:   for example for metabolite A in time 0 I have (12,16,17), time 24 (20,22,24) and time 48 (30,33,34) and son on.

the metabolites are assessed over time due their concentrations varied a lot. this is an experiment where I put X plant sample rich in metabolites combined with faecal sample (rich in bacteria). the bacteria hydrolyses metabolites, therefore their concentrations change over time

You do not have enough data for this to be anything more than a preliminary characterisation of the system. Graph the data points and assess them by eye while considering what you know about the particular metabolites. Then design an experiment to assess the behaviour of the interesting ones.

You certainly can conduct 40 separate 1-way ANOVA's, with the time point as your factor (3 levels). Or you could conduct 40 regressions, with the time point as your regressor. Since ANOVA is basically a special case of regression (see e.g. here, here, here, or here), chose which ever you are more comfortable with.
But...
At each time point, for any given metabolite, you only have 3 values. That sample is quite small. It may even beg the question; should you really run formal statistical tests (no matter what they are)? A statistical significance on a sample size of 3 may not be very convincing to your audience?
Furthermore, if you perform 40 ANOVA's, your chance to get at least 1 (or more) false significant one, just by chance (due to random sampling variations) is $87%$... So you need to adjust your $\alpha$ level for your 40 ANOVA's. Which will reduce your power, which is already low due the sample size. Having said this, the example data you gave in the comments is significant (both for for 1-way ANOVA and OLS regression) at the "traditional" .05 significance level and at the Bonferroni corrected level of .00125.
Note also that you also should check the ANOVA (or regression) assumptions for all 40 tests. The chance that they are "reasonably" met for all 40 tests may not be very high. And with only 9 residuals, you can truly only eyeball these assumptions...
With all the above caveats, you may indeed be better off just plotting your results, for each metabolite, with a linear fit, and eyeball the graphs; it should be clear which metabolites increase, which stay stable, etc...
A small note: if you decide to use ANOVA, I would not use Tukey, because it runs all comparisons, and thus further reduces your power, which is already challenged. I would use Dunnett instead, comparing to time 0 (which is basically a control). Yes, it is only 2 vs. 3, but, any little bit helps.

+1 However, I would not recommend a linear model for the time-course of metabolites in a mixed system like this. It is perfectly possible for the actual pattern to be a rise and then a fall. And with such tiny samples any statistical analysis that is not guided by detailed prior knowledge is going to be a random crapshoot.

@MichaelLew, I share your scepticism re. linear model. But with only 3 time points, fitting a higher order model is an even more futile endeavor. So linear is about all one can do...

@MichaelLew . I see is very interesting what you mention. In all the years of experience I have in biological experiments I have never seen any laboratories of analytical chemistry (where is my area of study) running more than a triplicate for a particular sample.  this because these types of experiments are expensive and requite tons of work to only run one triplicate for analysis. also if this is the case, why would you consider journal in sciences allow the publications of manuscripts providing only triplicates for statistical analysis?

@jginestet   . taking your advice of running Anova and Dunnet instead of Tukey to compare the control (time 0) against time 24 and tim 48 do you think this could be consider as a multiple t test comparison. If so, should I correct for P value with FDR. I know I only have triplicates for each time in each metabolite, this type of experiment is not like preliminary due there is not a different way to assess metabolization of chemical compounds by bacteria (known as microbiota sometimes).

@Ricardor, Dunnett will always control the FWER. YOur real problem is that you would perform 40 ANOVA's, which even if the null was true for all of them, would give you (on average) 2 significant results out of 40. As you say this is not a preliminary study (where controlling for false positives is less critical), so then this becomes a real issue.

@Ricardor, I agree with you that triplicates are routinely as many samples as one would collect for analytical chem. But I doubt anyone tries to compute p-values, confidence intervals, etc. out of the triplicates. The values may be averaged, or even one looks for positive/negative results, but rarely are formal statistical tests performed on these 3 values...

@Ricardor If the 3 datapoints are technical replicates then the data contain no information about the variabilities necessary for making inferences beyond this particular experiment. It cannot be considered to be more than a very preliminary survey of the system and statistical analysis will not help it be anything more. Graph the data.

@jginestet  . thanks for your suggestions I will follow your recommendation about using Dunnet. one last question, I am still learning statistics and would like to understand why running 40 separate Anova for each metabolite increases the false significant results of the p-value?. is it due I am testing the same type of H0 and H1 for each metabolite over time?. thanks

@ricardor, for every ANOVA you run, there is a 5% chance of a false positive (FP) result (significant, even when $H_0$ is true), assuming you use $\alpha=.05$). When you run 40 ANOVA's (or 40 significance tests), you can expect -on average- about 2 FP's, and the probability of getting at least 1 is .87 ($1-(0.95)^40). If this is a preliminary study (you will run confirmatory tests on the positives), then you may not care too much for FP's. But if this is a final study, or it will be published, you may need to protect against FP's.

@jginestet .Thanks a lot for your help. I know understand your point about increasing the error for every ANOVA run. yes the idea is to publish these data in a journal.

I think your idea makes total sense here. Just make sure to check for the assumptions of ANOVA, as metabolites might not display all the necessary properties in terms of homoscedasticity  etc. Mild violations could also be tolerated, it depends on the specific case.
In addition, remember to correct your p-values by multiple hypothesis testing: by chance, you are expected to get a few positive hits, and you want to be more stringent (use FDR).
Furthermore, as your variable is ordered, you might consider using a linear model (or a generalized one) to search for monotonic trends.
This post might help you: https://library.virginia.edu/data/articles/understanding-ordered-factors-in-a-linear-model

thanks for your recommendation. I was thinking in using tukey. So is it better to control the control the P values using FDR instead of running Ttukey tests?... Also, why could you help me to understand why is important to control P values in this case if each of the metabolites is compare only over time. I mean I not looking for differences between metabolites. thanks

You should never perform (or recommend) a 'correction' for multiplicity without knowing more about the context of the experiment than you know here. Protecting against false positive results at the cost of more false negative results is very damaging to preliminary research. See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630316/how-many-p-value-observations-do-you-think-are-required-before-doing-fdr-correct/630324#630324

@MichaelLew ok, I see your point. However, FDR is performed in the vast majority of cases with similar experimental settings. Pursuing the wrong candidate is also very damaging to research. Being at least aware that in 20 tests you expect one to be significant under the null hypothesis was the point, but I agree that more details always help getting a better direction

Thank for explaining that to me @gianMa ;-)  Did you read the linked answer?

Yes I did, and again you are right - I was giving some directions with the available info. Also, I know you know what FDR is and does, my clarification was meant for the OP.
