# Dealing with many positive-depenent insiginicant results in Benjamini-Hochberg-procedure

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I'm dealing with a statistical problem, where I tested a bunch of hypotheses with a very strong positive dependence within certain groups of them. Many of them didn't lead to significant results.
Now, the pure number of those positve-dependent insignificant results leads to all other null-hypotheses being accepted as well by the Benjamini-Hochberg-procedure, even though they clearly look wrong when looking at the actual data, so I believe that acceptance of those is overly conservative.

Is there anything I can do about this to still extract some significant findings here?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "positive-dependent insignificant hypotheses"?  Do you perhaps mean that the *data* used for testing two or more hypotheses are not independent?  If so, then you need to provide the specifics: how, exactly, are these data (and the tests based on them) dependent?

Comment: Are you sure you use the terminology correctly? Normally *null hypotheses* are rejected or not, the term "rejected" does not apply to the alternative. But you say "I believe that the rejection of those is overly conservative" - the term "conservative" means that rejection is harder and *fewer* null hypothesis are expected to be rejected by a conservative test.

Comment: "even though they clearly look true when looking at the actual data" - how exactly can you see this? In fact no model or hypothesis is ever literally "true". Of course data may not look like any indication against the null hypothesis, but even this can be deceptive, particularly with large sample sizes where small deviations from the null hypothesis can easily lead to rejection. (As said above I'm not actually sure whether it's the null hypothesis you're talking about here.)

Comment: The alternative will never be rejected.

Comment: Note also that you'd need to try any alternative to what you have already done on new independent data, as choosing another test for the reason that an earlier test didn't give you the significances you hoped for is invalid (the theory behind these tests doesn't allow you to pick a test dependent on other results on the same data).

Comment: The essence of multiple testing is that if you look at many things, some look "significant" by accident even if this doesn't mean anything. This doesn't only apply to tests, also it applies to looking at the data. So without any further information, (e.g., visualisation) I'm not convinced that the data really show that the null should be rejected and non-rejection is due to conservativity. It may well be that your visual diagnosis is affected by the multiple testing problem.

Comment: Any relevant information should be in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: This is not personal. What I want to believe or not is irrelevant. You don't present any evidence. You yourself write that you're "new to this", so on what basis could I take for granted that your "clearly look wrong" assessment is correct? The points that I am making are important to understand when doing analyses like this. I stop commenting now anyway.

Comment: The meaning of *independence* in any application of multiple corrections testing, like B-H, is that the *data* are independent between one test and the next.  It says *nothing* about the likelihoods related to the parameter.  That suggests you might be conceiving of this in a Bayesian way where you have some idea of a prior distribution of the parameter -- but so far, nothing in your post says anything about this crucial assumption.  Moreover, correcting for multiple hypothesis tests is irrelevant in a Bayesian setting, leaving us wondering what you are assuming and what's really going on.

Comment: It seems there is a lot of commentary here which is missing from the original question. Please edit your question to include these additional details, as many answerers may skip this section (and often do) because they get lost in a sea of comments. Editing this into the question provides a lot more context anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before getting tied up in questions of how to deal with the power-robbing effects of 'corrections' for multiplicity, you should first think about whether your inferences will be improved by such adjustments. This topic has been addressed many times on this site. Here are a couple of recent examples, and a quick search will reveal many more.

[p-value correction after wilcoxon/mann-whitney test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629990/p-value-correction-after-wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test/631414#631414)

[How many p-value observations do you think are required before doing FDR correction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630316/how-many-p-value-observations-do-you-think-are-required-before-doing-fdr-correct/630324#630324)

Comment: This was actually a good eye opener. Thank you!