# What statistic to use

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

My 8 year old daughter is conducting an experiment to assess memory. She has 3 groups. `Condition 1`, `Condition 2` and `Control`. Does she simply run a t-test for `group 1` against `Control` and then another t-test for `group 2` against `Control`, then a t-test for `group 1` against `group 2`?

Answer (score 2):

The most basic approach is a one-way [ANOVA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_analysis_of_variance). It will determine if any significant differences exist among Condition 1, Condition 2 and the Control. If you do find a significant difference then you can use a multiple comparison test (such as [Tukey's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test)) to determine which groups are different.

So, ANOVA for the general "are there differences" and Tukey for "Which are different". Looks like you want to do Tukey's test.

Comment: Note that Tukey's test controls the experiment-wise error rate across all 3 comparisons, & that's *not* conditional on the result of the ANOVA F-test. See ["Do we need a global test before post-hoc tests?"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9751/do-we-need-a-global-test-before-post-hoc-tests).

Comment: @Scortchi thanks...you've disabused me of a notion that was told to us in school...it makes sense, since Tukey does control for such errors. I was told...erroneously, I suppose, that Tukey's test was somehow conditional on a significant F-test...but i think they were confusing Tukey's test with Scheffe's test. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Scheffe's test doesn't rely on a previous ANOVA F-test to control the experiment-wise error rate either. Fisher's protected LSD does rely on a previous ANOVA F-test, (but doesn't truly control the experiment-wise error rate).

Comment: @Scortchi thanks for clarifying...I just took a look through some old textbooks...and lo and behold..Tukey's test is always presented as a "follow-up" test (although not strictly said that is must follow)...probably a source of a lot of the confusion.