# Alpha correction for simple effects

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I have a significant interaction between within and between factors. Planned contrasts for simple effects revealed significant difference in one group, but no difference in the other group (as expected). Do I need to employ alpha correction for the simple effects in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't think of any multiple comparison problems when you _wouldn't_ want to use alpha correction. Maybe [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148085/is-there-a-consensus-on-adjusting-alpha-for-multiple-contrasts-if-the-main-effec) question would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I read different approaches to this problems, some argue that we must correct for all multiple comparisons, and some argue that in small number of planned comparisons that derive from the interaction, alpha correction is not required.

Comment: Also, If I hypothesized that one comparison will yield non-significant results, do I need to include it in the number of multiple comparisons?