Post-hoc tests or multiple-corrected t-tests?
I am interested in the changes compared to the baseline in a specific gene, across about 15 timepoints  (with 3 samples per each time point).
Besides plotting, I could calculate 15 t-tests and perform a multiple-testing correction (bonferroni?). One can also perform an ANOVA followed by post-hoc Dunett's test.

Which would make more sense (given that I am only interested in the post-hoc results of the ANOVA, not in the omnibus results itself ) ?

Which one would be more powerful?



There are many questions on this site already that address this question, for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517775/what-is-more-powerful-an-anova-test-or-post-hoc-tests, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515582/comparing-two-or-more-independent-paired-t-tests. Do these answer your questions or is there something more specific you want to ask that is not covered in other questions?

Are you sure you want to compare each time point to control (what Dunnett would do)? Have you considered looking at the trend over time?
